# Practical code-friendly name for non-owning smart-pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

We are since C++11 blessed with a rather complete set of smart-pointer types:

- std::shared_ptr
- std::weak_ptr
- std::unique_ptr
- std::auto_ptr (deprecated)

But missing is a smart-pointer without ownership, integrated whith the above.

This seems to lead developer discussions into a somewhat loose classification that commonly has phrases like 'that is a non-owning smart-pointer'. But this is not a good name that I want to use in naming a pointer-wrapper template in my code.

Is there any suggestions for a better code-friendly name for a non-owning smart-pointer?

```
template<typename T>
struct NonOwningSmart_pointer;
```

There is std::weak_ptr which does not really fill the requirements as it requires shared_ptr.

Update: the main benefit of naming this type of smart-pointer uniquely is code clarity, construction to nullptr and playing well with the other std pointer types.

Comment: How is a weak pointer different from whatever this "NonOwningSmart_pointer" is?

Comment: A std::weak_ptr is always associated with std::shared_ptr, as I understand. But there's std::unique_ptr and also raw.

Comment: Why do you need non-owning smart pointer in the first place? What is the benefit over plain pointer?

Comment: Well if you follow the cpp core guidelines then a raw pointer is always a non owning pointer.  Only `owner` or smart pointers are considered owners.  This kind of makes life easy if you use this method as you just assume all raw pointers are not yours to manage.  Personally I like this approach.

Comment: `referring_ptr` or just use `std::reference_wrapper_t`

Comment: Well then, it sounds to me like a "plain pointer" is what this mythical kind of a pointer is. It doesn't own the object.

Comment: @PiotrNycz - referring_ptr is nice, but it would be nice to have a null state which as I understand std::reference_wrapper_t is without.

Comment: How is your smart pointer different from a raw pointer? What smart features does it support?

Comment: the simplest is `template <typename T> using referring_ptr = T*;` - but just consider if this is better than raw `T*`?

Comment: It depends on what your non-owning smart pointer does. For example, it can be a `Non_null_pointer`, if that's what it does. Or it can a `Non_owning_shared` for a subclass of `shared_ptr` that uses a no-op deleter. Whatever. Make sure your name is meaningful, or else, if there is no meaningful name at all, the concept is probably not meaningful either.

Comment: @anatolyg - Well, as the discussions goes raw pointer is what's wrapped in all types of pointers.

Comment: @anatolyg - This NonOwningSmart_pointer provides only cloning from shared_ptr and unique_ptr without any side effects, and does nothing on destruction.

Comment: @"Cheers and hth. - Alf" - Actually it should be something like "Non-owning out of some type of smart that will guarantee to keep pointed-to object alive while I'm working on it, and I promise to not store it somewhere bad". Common use-case is as input to function.

Comment: Might be of interest/revance "Herb Sutter - Distinguishing between maybe-null vs never-null is the important thing" https://herbsutter.com/2017/02/15/distinguishing-between-maybe-null-vs-never-null-is-the-important-thing/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was even a proposal for something like this:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4282.pdf

There it was named 'observer_ptr'.
The proposal was rejected, but the same idea was discussed (with a somewhat more positive feedback) on the Boost mailing list just recently.

Comment: Owners and observers, and this middleground weak.  Yes I think I like it, best so far.

Comment: "N4282: A Proposal for the World’s Dumbest Smart Pointer, v4" - the title made my day ;)

Comment: Here's some reasoning for rejection: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1408r0.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The C++ Core Guidelines seem to suggest using raw pointers for non-owning pointers.  I guess, technically, they say to use smart pointers to indicate ownership and to assume raw pointers are non-owning.  I guess that doesn't rule out using a smart pointer for a non-owning pointer, but I don't see what advantage that would provide.

Comment: The advantage is that you see the pointer and immediately know that it's non-owning. If it's just `T*`, then you have to inspect the code or the documentation to find out.

Comment: Also not all raw-pointers are about object lifetime and ownership. I always use some type to clear what kind of role a pointer is in.

Comment: @ChristianHackl:  Not if you follow the core guidelines.  If you see a `T*`, then you do know it's a non-owning pointer.

Comment: But a raw pointer might point to a substring or a device control register etc, not within object lifetime management at all. And most legacy code is not clear about raw pointers.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: You may be working in a huge project with many different developers, inconsistent coding styles and a mix of new code and legacy code.

Comment: @Jojje:  Given that the question is about introducing a non-owning smart pointer, I assumed it was early enough in the project that you were considering how to consistently mark non-owning pointers.  If you have legacy code that cannot be made consistent with whichever solution you choose, then I'm not sure what's to be gained by introducing a non-owning smart pointer in only limited context.

Comment: As for substrings, you probably want to use a range, StringPiece, string_view, array_view or other abstraction that captures more than just the pointer.

Comment: @"Adrian McCarthy": Legacy code with lots of raw-pointers is a reality, I'm afraid,  and I don't follow why this is an obstacle to design new and modified code in a presumed better way ?